# Online Security and Storing Monetary Values in a Database

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, web

I'm building an e-commerce app for an online store, and I'm planning to have a credit system so customers can earn credits to purchase products.

Handling credits I have no problems with, but I'm uneasy about the idea of storing values with actual monetary value in my MySQL database.

Currently I'm planning to have a table for Credits with a foreign key that links it to a user, so I can figure out a user's amount of Credits by a single JOIN.

I just wanted to ask if there are things that I should be careful with, lest I leave vulnerabilities that could be avoided.

Thanks!

Comment: store monetary values with a decimal(10,2), if you are going to work with decimal you can also use 3 or 4 places after comma.. The data type works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

First, as Fernando mentions in the comments, use `decimal` to store the value.

Have audit trails, that way you can go back and determine why a value is the value it is.

Your biggest challenge will be making sure your system is secure, not so much how it is stored (although that obviously comes into security as well). Make sure the app is tested, perhaps with a proper pen testing tool to start with. Make sure the product machine is locked down and audited.

It (almost) goes without saying that **reliable** and **tested** backups are extremely important when dealing with something of value.

I'm also assuming that you are not handling credit card transactions directly? Just in case you are, I urge you to reconsider and use a third party because there is a lot that can go wrong for you (or your customers). Plus, you don't want to have to deal with PCI-DSS.

Comment: The credits system is a separate entity, and is used so we can reward customers.  I'm going to be handling credit card transactions using a third-party merchant, because like you said, I don't want to deal with PCI compliance.

I imagined that most of the security of such a system would rely on the security of the actual database, but I'll be hosting this on a normal VPS, and really my only option is to hope that my provider will keep me safe.

Comment: I was just wondering if there were best practices I was unaware of when storing records with monetary value.